# Validate the value of a field of a object based on the values of objects located in other files using JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to validate that the value of a field in a json coincides with the values of the fields of other objects located in different files using Json Schema.

Take that I have several Scripts.json files like this:

**Script1.json**

```
{"scriptname": "script1", "type": "script" }
```

**Script2.json**

```
{"scriptname": "script2", "type": "script" }
```

These files have a schema like this

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "scriptname": {"type": "string"}
    "type": {"type": "string"}
  }
}
```

Then I have another file called **UseScript.json**

```
{"script": "script1" }
```

with schema
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
"type":"object",
"properties": {
"script": {"type": "string"}
}
}

What I look is that the validator search all the files in a folder with type "script" and then compare it with the value of field "script" in UseScript.json.

How can I reference the scriptname from the script1.json in the schema? When searching, I only found references within the schema using $ref, but what I look is references in the json.

Is it possible at all?